# Movie about an alien girl with amnesia running around a ship

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

This movie is a low budget movie and feels like a Syfy original movie. Though I'm not sure if it is. I saw it on TV, as a kid a decade or two ago. I've checked the Syfy listings, and "alien girl movies" lists on Google and couldn't find it.

From what I remember, it has a woman running around an alien ship being scared, lost, and confused. Later, she is taken into a room where a doctor asks her questions. The doctor holds up a sign with alien markings and asks her what they are; the woman doesn't know. The doctor holds up a second sign with alien markings and asks what they are; the woman doesn't know.

At the end of the movie, it turns out the woman running around was actually an alien that lost her memories and the doctor was testing if she got her memories back. The doctor asks her questions again, holding up the sign with alien markings, asking what they are. The woman replies, "letters." The doctor holds up the second sign with alien markings. The woman replies, "numbers." Proving the woman got her memories back and that she is in fact an alien.

Answer (score 6):

*Alien Abduction* (2005).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0426396/):

> After being abducted by extra terrestrials, Jean and her friends are committed to a top secret government run mental institution to undergo tests and be brainwashed.

[Wikipedia's detailed summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Abduction_(2005_film)) offers more matching details:

> That night while they are sitting around the campfire, the aliens attack. The four flee for their lives but cannot escape, and they are abducted. [...]
>
> **Jean awakens in a hospital, suffering from terrible flashbacks.** That night, a shadowy figure sneaks into her room and staples something into the back of her neck, **causing the flashbacks to stop and leaving Jean with no memory of the abduction.**
>
> **Jean is questioned by a staff psychiatrist**, Dr. Booker, who reveals that she is in a special facility for UFO abductees. [...]
>
> Jean breaks into another wing of the hospital to find her friends. [...] She wanders around the basement, looking for a way out through the vents, until she finds an empty storage room. [...] Thomas shows Jean the way out and reveals that **the hospital is actually part of the alien ship.**
>
> Dr. Brooks removes Jean's memory suppression chip, and she now has access to the aliens' collective memory. **This enables her to recognize the alien symbols and numbers shown to her on cards that she had not recognized when her memory was suppressed.** She says that she is now "ready to serve" out the mission from Earth.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi movie woman without memories alien symbols site:en.wikipedia.org/wiki`.